# "Big" TeX won't get hidden by `!>`?

Tags: support, mathjax, spoilers

I just posted an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488750/convergence-of-series-problem/488794#488794) but I am finding it impossible for `>!` to work with the `\begin{align}` environment. How can this be fixed?

Comment: The spoiler tag was added for sites like Gaming, SciFi and similar sites that deal with spoilers to games, movies or books. It was never meant to work in combination with MathJax, so I'm not suprised that it fails in certain cases there. Anything but plain text in a spoiler is pretty much an unsupported feature that might, or might not work.

Comment: Another posts concerning problems with MathJax in spoiler area: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9297/how-to-put-math-equations-in-a-spoiler-block) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox/4365#4365).

Comment: As a smallish note, the MathJax rendering method (on the user's end) may also cause problems.  As far as I've been able to discern, spoiler-ed math will be correctly hidden under the HTML-CSS option, but will not be hidden under SVG.  (`[right-click math]` $\blacktriangleright$ `Math Settings` $\blacktriangleright$ `Math Renderer` $\blacktriangleright$ `[option]`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works if you don't try to include linebreaks in the MathJax. I took out the linebreaks and it works fine. Do the whole thing on one line.

Comment: Thank you. ${}{}{}{}$