# How to leave lines in between `>!`?

Tags: support, mathjax, spoilers

I'll get directly into the question.

When I do something like:

```
 >! (Some text)
 >!
 >! (Some other text)
```

It appears as:

> (Some text)
>  
>  (Some text)

How would I get these to appear on separate lines?

I have tried incorporating `$$$$`, but then the text just becomes too far apart in terms of spacing, especially when dealing with numbers. For example:

```
 >! $\frac 12$ vs $\frac 11$ 
 >! $$$$
 >! (Some text)
 >! $$$$
 >! $\frac 12$ vs $\frac 11$
```

produces:

> $\frac 12$ vs $\frac 11$ 
>  $$$$
>  (Some text)
>  $$$$
>  $\frac 12$ vs $\frac 11$

**Is there an efficient technique to deal with the problem of text not appearing in separate lines?**

Comment: This past discussion seem related: [“Big” TeX won't get hidden by `!>`?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10906) and [Is it possible to spoiler multi-line mathjax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26943)

Comment: I want to do it with text as well as math.

Answer (score 7):

You can see how I did this below. Note that there is no use of mathjax or some other side-channel approach.

```
>! This is a line.  
>!  
>! This is another line.
```

> This is a line.
>
>  This is another line.

Take careful notice the pairs of spaces at the end of lines, which is quite important.

Comment: This is useful also in other contexts here.  A line ending with two spaces is a "forced" line ending.